# How can I send params to a function called interval

Tags: python, parameters

```
def interval(start,stop=None,step=1):
    if stop is None:
        start, stop=0,start
    result=[]
    i=start
    while i<stop:
        result.append(i)
        i+=step
    return result
```

If I call the function by `interval(10)`, the result is `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. the question is: which param receives the `10`? I think it should be the `stop`, but I don't know how the program did that. And why does the program know the start is `0`? And what's the meaning of the `if stop is None: start,stop=0,start`?

Comment: Please try to add real sample code.

Answer (score 1):

```
if stop is None:
    start, stop=0,start
```

is equivalent to

```
if stop is None:
    stop = start
    start = 0
```

Calling `interval(10)` is equivalent to calling `interval(10, None, 1)`. At the very start of the function, `start` will be `10` and `stop` will be `None`, but this `if` block will then change `start` to `0` and `stop` to `10`.

Comment: but how could the "start, stop=0,start"equivalent to "stop=start,start=0"? I can not understand it.

Comment: First, `start,stop=0,start` is not equivalent to `stop=start,start=0`, because `stop=start,start=0` is not a valid line of python. `start,stop=0,start` is equivalent to running `start=0` and `stop=start` simultaneously. As to how, this is just how Python syntax works. In Python, `left1, left2 = right1, right2` means "assign `right1` to `left1` and "assign `right2` to `left2`".

Comment: One thing that may be confusing is that the syntax is different depending on whether it's found in a function definition or just on a line. If you have a function definition `def f(a, b=c, d):` the syntax `a, b=c, d` is telling you that the function has parameters `a`, `b,` and `d` and that the default value of `b` is `c`. On the other hand, if you just have `a, b=c, d` by itself on a line, this means assign `c` to `a` and assign `d` to `b`. Thus, the syntax `a, b=c,d` might mean different things depending on the context surrounding it.